# How to simulate realistic speed in PyGame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to define a realistic walking speed (meters per second) for all `worker` objects. How can I do it?

Currently I have the parameter `speed` in the code. This parameter is initialised as `randint(2, 4)` - random integer between 2 and 4. But this value is not mapped to real scales.

In my case it's known that 1 pixel refers to `0.038` meters. Also, we know the walking and running human speed:

```
METERS_PER_PIXEL = 0.038370147
AVG_WALK_SPEED = 1.4 # meters per second
MIN_RUN_SPEED = 2.0  # meters per second
MAX_RUN_SPEED = 5.0  # meters per second
```

Having these constants, I want to introduce one more parameter called `human_speed`. For example, I want to initialise `human_speed` of `worker` equal to `1.4`. How can I convert `1.4` to `speed` so that `pygame` can implement correct animations? 
I need `human_speed` for some backend calculations.

```
import pygame, random
import sys

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (20, 255, 140)
GREY = (210, 210 ,210)

SCREENWIDTH=1000
SCREENHEIGHT=578  


class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location, *groups):
        self._layer = -1
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, groups)

        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(image_file).convert(), (SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=location)


class Worker(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location, *groups):

        self._layer = 1
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, groups)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(image_file).convert_alpha(), (40, 40))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=location)
        self.change_direction()
        self.speed = random.randint(2, 4)


    def change_direction(self):

        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(random.randint(-100, 100), random.randint(-100, 100))

        while self.direction.length() == 0:
            self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(random.randint(-100, 100), random.randint(-100, 100)) 

        self.direction = self.direction.normalize()


    def update(self, screen):

        if random.uniform(0,1)<0.005:
            self.change_direction()

        vec = [int(v) for v in self.direction * self.speed]
        self.rect.move_ip(*vec)

        if not screen.get_rect().contains(self.rect):
            self.change_direction()
        self.rect.clamp_ip(screen.get_rect())

pygame.init()

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
workers = pygame.sprite.Group()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("TEST")

# create multiple workers
for pos in ((0,0), (100, 100), (200, 100)):
    Worker("worker.png", pos, all_sprites, workers)

Background("background.jpg", [0,0], all_sprites)

carryOn = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while carryOn:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            carryOn = False

    all_sprites.update(screen)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(20)
```

Comment: Can't you do `1.4 / 0.038` to get pixels per second? That's about 37 px/s

Comment: @NChauhan: But how should I use these pixels per second? Should I set `speed` equal to `37`? In this case `worker` objects will fly like rockets on the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do `1.4` meters per second, and `0.038` meters are `1` pixel, you do `1.4 / 0.038 = 36.8` pixels per second.

If you have a framerate of 20, that means your average worker shoud move `1/20` of those `36.8` pixels, resulting in `1.84` pixels per frame.

That's the easy part, because there are some problems, like:

- If you store the position of your `Sprite` in a `Rect`, you'll get rounding errors because a `Rect` can only handle integers, not floating point numbers. But you could create a `Vector2` to store the precise position and just round the coordinates every time you move and store them in the `Rect`.
- Inconsistent movement may appear if you solely rely on the fixed target framerate to calculate the distance you want to move. Usually you use something called delta time, which basically means you keep track of the time each frame took to run, and pass that value to your `update` function and use it to calculate the distance.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Could you please explain what is "framerate of 20"?

Comment: @ScalaBoy in your main loop, you call `clock.tick(20)` which will wait long enough so ensure that your loop only runs 20 times per second, hence a framerate of 20 frames per second.